# Need help regarding dimentions of vectors in matrix transformation

Tags: linear-transformations

Suppose $T(x) = Ax$ ,let $A$ be a $3$x$4$ matrix filled with numbers (3 rows & 4 columns). How can I find dimensions of vectors that are inputs and also dimensions of outputs for the function $T(x) = Ax$.

Comment: Do you know when matrix-by-matrix multiplication makes sense?

Comment: yup when rows of 1st matrix and col of 2nd matrix are equall

Comment: i know basics of matrix, just don't know about transformations as it is new to me

Comment: There's your answer.  Your $x$ is a column vector, and the result is a column vector.

Comment: @Randall i'm still a little confused, you are saying that no. of columns is input? and no. of rows is output? these are the dimensions?

Comment: I just answered below.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101091/discussion-between-abdurrafay-and-randall).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A$ is $3 \times 4$, $x$ is supposed to be an $n \times 1$ column vector, and $Ax$ is to be a column vector, too.  The only way $Ax$ can make sense when $A$ is $3 \times 4$ and $x$ is $n \times 1$ is for $n=4$. The resulting vector $Ax$ must be $3 \times 1$.

I should add, I've assumed your inputs to be vectors.  It is not inconceivable that $x$ could mean a matrix, so that $Ax$ was also a matrix.  For instance, $x$ could mean a $4 \times 2$ matrix, in which case the output $Ax$ is a $3 \times 2$ matrix, not a column vector.